# Branded FA5 icons not working

Tags: font-awesome

I am running Font Awesome % on my site (static).
[image: Only the non-branded icons are working]

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-v2Tw72dyUXeU3y4aM2Y0tBJQkGfplr39mxZqlTBDUZAb9BGoC40+rdFCG0m10lXk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-q3jl8XQu1OpdLgGFvNRnPdj5VIlCvgsDQTQB6owSOHWlAurxul7f+JpUOVdAiJ5P" crossorigin="anonymous">

    ......

  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    ..........fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                <a target="_Blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/timsmith25/">LinkedIn</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                <a target="_Blank" href="https://github.com/WebRuin">Github</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="fab fa-codepen"></i>
                <a target="_Blank" href="https://codepen.io/WebRuin/">CodePen</a>
              </li>
.....

  </body>
</html>
```

My first thought was that it is happening because I am on `localhost:xxx`

I have it up on GitHub here: https://webruin.github.io/Resume/

Is this A problem that is known? Am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the prefix `fab` indicates, you want to use brand icons. So you also have to include the .CSS for it. Here's your snippet again with the correct `link`-tag added:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/brands.css" integrity="sha384-IiIL1/ODJBRTrDTFk/pW8j0DUI5/z9m1KYsTm/RjZTNV8RHLGZXkUDwgRRbbQ+Jh" crossorigin="anonymous">        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-v2Tw72dyUXeU3y4aM2Y0tBJQkGfplr39mxZqlTBDUZAb9BGoC40+rdFCG0m10lXk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-q3jl8XQu1OpdLgGFvNRnPdj5VIlCvgsDQTQB6owSOHWlAurxul7f+JpUOVdAiJ5P" crossorigin="anonymous">

    ......

  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    ..........fab fa-linkedin"></i>
                <a target="_Blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/timsmith25/">LinkedIn</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                <a target="_Blank" href="https://github.com/WebRuin">Github</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="fab fa-codepen"></i>
                <a target="_Blank" href="https://codepen.io/WebRuin/">CodePen</a>
              </li>
.....

  </body>
</html>
```